# Preventing injection via the projection in a Content Provider query (parameterization?)

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a Content Provider which I tested with the [Drozer](https://www.mwrinfosecurity.com/products/drozer) framework and it turned out that the projection in the `query()` method is vulnerable to injection. Including "* FROM SQLITE_MASTER --" lists all tables. Which is the best way to guard against this? I added filtering of certain characters:

```
public Cursor query(Uri contentUri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs,
        String sortOrder) {

    /*
     * Filter queries that contain certain characters to guard against SQL injection
     */
    for (String query : projection) {
        if (query.contains("*") || query.contains(";") || query.contains("'") || query.contains("\"")) {
            //Possible SQL injection attack, leave the query
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I understand that blacklist filtering is not the way to go and parameterizing the projection would be better. However I can't see a way to do this in the `query()` method. It doesn't have two arguments like the selection has "selection" then "selectionArgs". How best to guard against injection without blacklisting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to allow your content provider's clients to use arbitrarily complex SQL, there is nothing much you can do; a projection like `SomeColumn AS "* FROM sqlite_master -- ;'"""` would be perfectly valid and harmless.
To prevent access to sensitive data, that data would have to be in another database.

However, you could impose the restriction that clients can read only a predefined set of columns, unchanged.
To enforce this, check that all strings in `projection` are equal to one of those column names.

Comment: So you would whitelist rather than blacklist? Maybe: check the table name for the content provider name, and if each string in the projection array is not equal to one of the column names for that table, throw exception?

Comment: That's what I wrote. Or you just say that clients are allowed to read everything in your DB.

Answer (score 0):

Probably easily way to prevent against SQL injection in projection parameter is to use [setProjectionMap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html#setProjectionMap(java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%3E)) method on `SQLiteQueryBuilder`. As stated in documentation,

> If a projection map is set it must contain all column names the user may request, even if the key and value are the same.

I tried to fix a vulnerable content provider by adding this method, and here is what drozer showed me:

```
dz> run app.provider.query content://myContentProvider/myPath/ --projection "'"
Invalid column '
```